# Multiple spring boot jar deployment open liberty

Tags: spring-boot, open-liberty

How to deploy multiple spring boot application jar in open liberty server?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple SpringBoot uber jar applications running in the same Liberty server.  You will need to either use multiple Liberty servers or you will need to change to use the war option for SpringBoot.  You can deploy multiple SpringBoot war applications to a single Liberty server.

Comment: thank you Jared for the answer